# How to have nodes execute read operations concurrently?

Tags: cassandra

I am experimenting with Cassandra 3.0.2 on a 6-node cluster and found "unintuitive" read-scaling/-workload patterns.

Query:

```
select count(*) from dvds
```

where dvd has 280k records.

With default vnode settings (num_tokens: 256), I've found that increasing node count from 1 to 2 improves read performance by about 35%, but each additional node beyond 2 nodes decreases performance by about 30%.

With vnode-s disabled (num_tokens: 1 and initial_token-s set manually), a 6-node cluster performs about 35% better than with num_tokens: 256, but the following pattern is clearly observable: The coordinator node's CPU consumption is either about 50% (of the total capacity of a CPU core) or about 110-120%, whereas the other nodes consume either about 0% or 60-70% percent capacity of a single core. The unintuitive part is this: when one node is busy, the other nodes are idle. (When the coordinator CPU consumption is at 110-120%, all the other nodes are pretty idle. When the coordinator's CPU is 50%, one of the other nodes is busy.)

The strongest hypothesis I could come up with was that the cluster is unable to handle the network traffic, but the coordinator's network traffic (where, I assume, a network scalability issue would hardest hit) didn't seem to exceed 1Mb/s at any point in time. (The network interfaces' throughputs on the nodes are 10/100 Mbps.) Also, with a network scalability issue, I would expect the "num_tokens: 1" setup to show initially high CPU load on all nodes (with the exception of the coordinator) -- or at least some evenly distributed simultaneous load.

Please, can anybody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 5):

count(*) has its place, but is very expensive. The coordinator essentially has to pull everything down from all the nodes, merge, and count them. The only thing it provides over "read everything" and counting them locally is reducing some network load between coordinator and your application.

If you need this metric regularly I would recommend using a counter or lwt to keep the count a single read operation (create data model around queries not abstractions of the data). If need it once, or infrequently, hadoop/spark is a great option. Also you can get a decent estimate from the EstimatedPartitionSize metric (per node though) depending on your data model.

Comment: Many thanks, Chris!
Actually, I am planning to use Cassandra tables as the "backing store" for Spark. I am going through this simple exercise to understand "in isolation" (before adding Spark to the lot) the performance implications of creating an RDD using sc.cassandraTable(). So far count(*) seems **to most closely simulate the workload to be expected on Cassandra** (any pointers to the contrary are welcome). It seems that -- with my current Cassandra-config -- RDD partitions will be loaded in a serial fashion (not in parallel), which I suspect is a behavior that can/should be improved on.

Comment: So, to explain the behavior you are seeing with increasing nodes. If the coordinator owns all the data and its a CL.ONE query, it skips a lot of work that it would normally have to do, and the decreased network hops in collection also may improve performance. There is a slight jump in performance with small clusters, but that jump should be ignored since its kinda artificial. For testing you should start with like a 5 node cluster and increase from there to get a better feel.

Comment: vnodes impact on performance is generally negative. Queries/repairs have to walk each range; generally sequentially, which will be slower especially in cases where there are a lot of empty ranges which was then wasted effort. That said I would still /strongly/ recommend using vnodes for operational simplicity, manual token management is a pain.

Comment: Keep in mind also in CPU monitoring, the coordinator on a count(*) has to do a lot of work that is not normally necessary and it has to load a lot into memory which even if immediately discarded can cause a lot of heap pressure. The high CPU (may) be attributed to additional garbage collections. Spark should do a better job of distributing the load instead of putting it all on the one coordinator.

Comment: > Spark should do a better job of distributing the load instead of putting it all on the one coordinator. |

And indeed,
    val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("mykeyspace", "dvds");
    println(rdd.count);
results in a work-load much more evenly distributed across nodes than a Cassandra-level count(*). Interesting...

Thanks, again Chris.